# DNS Problems with Heroku

Tags: heroku, web, dns, hosting

I'm having some problems configuring the DNS settings for my custom domain to work correctly on Heroku.

I have set the DNS records as follows:

```
Host                 Type            Points to
example.com          WR              www.example.com
www.example.com      CNAME           example.herokuapp.com
www.example.com.au   CNAME           example.herokuapp.com
```

However, the 'www.example.com' domain sometimes fails to load on my computer, as well as my client's phone. It seems rare for this domain to fail (it works fine on everyone else's computers that I've asked), but the fact that it doesn't work on mine and my client's computers is a problem.

However, the '.com.au' domain (and the heroku one) always works. Why is this?

Is there anything wrong with the configuration above? I followed the ['custom domain names' article on heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) to reach this configuration (I don't have much experience with DNS, unfortunately). The DNS provider I am using does not support ANAME or ALIAS so I went with the above config instead.

Thanks. Any help in getting the '.com' domain working on every device would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, it may be a lot of things, DNS caching and other stuff.

But if you don't have a lot of DNS records, I suggest you use a heroku add-on like PointDNS (https://addons.heroku.com/pointdns) as it supports ALIAS.